# How I can count the number of times that a element repeat inside a list, if the element itself is a list

Tags: list

list = [[ '1', '2'], [ '1', '2'], [ '1', '2'], ['3','4'], ['3','4'],['3','4'],['3','4']]

I would like to print out
print( 'the element  [ '1', '2'] repeat 3 times')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as with any other element check:

```py
>>> x.count(['1', '2'])
3
```

You can wrap this up in a function:

```py
def f(v):
  print(f'Item "{v}" appears {x.count(v)} times in {x}')
```